# What is the number of all possible non-cyclic simple paths in a fully-connected directed graph?

Tags: graph, formula, depth-first-search, directed-graph

Let's say we have a fully connected digraph `G` with `N` vertices and `M` edges.

How many edges does the graph have? Is it `M = N^2`?

If we take one vertex and start visiting its neighbors in a 'depth-first search' manner and avoiding loops, how many non-cyclic simple paths will we get?

For example, if we start from vertex 1 in a graph of 4 vertices, here are the paths:

```
- 1
- 1,2
- 1,3
- 1,4
- 1,2,3
- 1,2,4
- 1,3,2
- 1,3,4
- 1,4,2
- 1,4,3
```

Is it `N!` or more for a graph with `N` vertices? I could not find a way to generalize this and to derive a usable formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your graph is full, there are `n!` simple paths for each vertex, so total of `n*n!` simple paths in the graph.

let a starting vertex be `v_1`.

There are `|V|` possibilities what to do next: move to one of each `V\{v_1}`,  or stop.

next you have `|V|-1` possibilities: move to one of each `V\{v_1,v_2}` [where v_2 is the node chosen as second] or stop.

... [do induction to formally prove it here]

after you have a path of `n` nodes, there is one only possibility: stop.

 giving you total of `n*(n-1)*...*1 = n!` possible simple paths for each vertex, and `n*n!` total possible simple paths in the graph

Comment: Thank you, amit! Could you advise a simple-to-comprehend source to read about induction for beginners?