# Python and list mutability in an all-paths algorithm

Tags: python, immutability, graph-algorithm, depth-first-search

I've been working on a all-simple-paths algorithm in python based off of [networkx's version](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/_modules/networkx/algorithms/simple_paths.html#all_simple_paths). At the moment the only changes I'm trying to make are to get it to get ALL paths for ALL nodes without doing it inside of a O(n^2) double loop.

I believe I have the main algorithm sorted, but I'm not quite used to the mutability of Python's list structure and I think that's what's messing up the algorithm.

I've written a similar program in Java so I know how many paths there should be on a test graph, but I can't seem to even get the numbers reasonably close.

```
def _all_simple_paths_graph(DG, cutoff):
    uniquePaths = []
    nlist = DG.nodes()
    for source in nlist:
        uniqueTreePaths = []
        if cutoff < 1:
            return
        visited = [source]
        stack = [iter(DG[source])]
        while stack:
            children = stack[-1]
            child = next(children, None)
            if child is None:
                stack.pop()
                visited.pop()
            elif len(visited) < cutoff:
                if child not in visited:
                    visited.append(child)
                    stack.append(iter(DG[child]))
                    if visited not in uniqueTreePaths:
                        yield visited
                        uniqueTreePaths.append(visited)
            else: #len(visited) == cutoff:
                if visited not in uniqueTreePaths:
                    yield visited + [child]
                    uniqueTreePaths.append(visited)
                stack.pop()
                visited.pop()
    uniquePaths.extend(uniqueTreePaths)
```

Can anyone tell me where I've gone wrong? I believe it's to do with where `visited` should be mutable and where it shouldn't. However, I could also have got the basic functionality wrong, I'm fairly new to Python!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify what the symptom is. Is the yielded stuff wrong, or is `uniquePaths` wrong?  It looks like that the function yields the right paths, but at the end of the function, `uniquePaths` has far fewer paths than it should, and they're all empty.

The reason why there's not enough paths, is that `uniquePaths.extend(uniqueTreePaths)` is not at the right indention.

The problem you're here for, is that `visited` is a mutable list. In Python, all lists are mutable. In fact, that's the reason this algorithm works. `visited` is treated like a stack that happens to be the path. When you append `visited` to `uniqueTreePaths` multiple times, you are really appending the same object over and over again. When you modify `visited`, all of them are modified.

To fix this problem, you should append a copy of the list. This is going to be fairly expensive memory-wise, but you wanted all unique paths in a graph, so you should've been aware of that already. You can use `uniqueTreePaths.append(list(visited))` to make a new `list` object out of `visited`. I would actually create a tuple out of it, so that it can't be modified: `uniqueTreePaths.append(tuple(visited))`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out where my mutability was incorrect. It appears correct, but my understanding is that a complete graph should have n*n! simple paths. In my case a complete 3 graph should be 3*3! = 18, but it only calculates 15 (if you include the base cases), and I can only calculate 15 myself. Do you know if the algorithm is wrong, or if my knowledge of simple paths is? :)

Comment: I think n*n! is wrong. Looking at the proof at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8457805/what-is-the-number-of-all-possible-non-cyclic-simple-paths-in-a-fully-connected The "stop" choice should not be treated the same as node choice, hence you can't just multiply.

Comment: That's where I got the n*n! formula from, it's in the answer: 'and n*n! total possible simple paths in the graph'.